# Strange Digital Assets Library Behaviour

Tags: 2010, document-library

I am having a bit of an issue with a Digital Assets library.

When I view the page, everything seems as it should, with the pictures located in the library, and the thumbnails being stored in _t.

The issue is, for some users (and only some not all) the thumbnails show correctly, but when trying to actually view the files they get a Red X (which I am assuming means that the file can't be found).

I would think it would be a right issue, but they can see the library and all its contents and can even see the thumbnails, so this has me kind of stumped.

Has anyone seen this and know why it is happening/how to to fix or has seen something similar to this before?

Thanks, 
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Usually that means the user doesn't have the correct permission to the picture